# How to get extra properties from selected item using React DropdownButton

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm a Java developer working on a react prototype and stuck trying to retrieve the id property from the selected dropdown item, which we then should post to our api. The value shown for the user on the dropdown option is an actor's name whereas the api needs their id.
I think I may be getting the syntax for this wrong somewhere but I can't see where. I've tried adding extra params to the `handleSelect` call, created another new handleClick function and added it to Dropdown. Item instead of `DropdownButton`, changed params and calls around, but I only get undefined for these fields and am running out of ideas now.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
<DropdownButton 
onSelect={handleSelect} 
title={selected?.key || list[0].key}>
{list.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <Dropdown.Item key={index} eventKey=. 
            {item.key} onSelect={handleClick}>
            {item.key}
            </Dropdown.Item>
           );
        })}
 </DropdownButton>
```

```
const handleSelect = (key, event, value) => {
  setSelected({
    key: key,
    value: event.target.value
  })

  setActorId(getSelectedActorId(value))
}

const handleClick = (eventKey, event) => {
  console.log(eventKey)
  console.log(event)
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown.Item just has a onClick property, but not an onSelect property: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-item-props. When you just need the actor's id for submitting, then I would only safe the id in the state and nothing else.

I have created a sandbox with some dummy data: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-blackwell-h7s7op

- Create a state for actor id
- Set this state onSelect of the DropdownButton
- Set appropriate eventKey to Dropdown.Item when iterating, so you get them out of onSelect callback

Edit: Dropdown is a button with an overlay menu. You usually don't display the selected valu in the button. For this case i would recommend you to use Form.Select component. I have adjusted the sandbox accordinly.

Edit2: I have also added a hacky dropdown button which changes its title according to the selected value. But I wouldn't recommend you doing it this way.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. It's really great and I'm very thankful. Just a small question please. Before I had the names of the actors displaying back to the dropdown once they were selected and I'm not sure how to have this back again with the piece from codesandbox.

Comment: ```<DropdownButton title={actors[index].name} onSelect={(eventKey) => 
       selectActorId(eventKey)}>{actors.map((actor, index) => {return 
              (<Dropdown.Item
                     key={index}
                     eventKey={actor.id}
                      active={actor.id === selectedActorId}>
                       {actor.name}
                       </Dropdown.Item>
               );
               })}
</DropdownButton> ```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but that's more or less what I'm trying to get, either the name or perhaps the index of the selected actor to add it back to the title for the dropdown.

Comment: I have adjusted the sandbox. Please look into it.

Comment: Thanks. That would work in the sandbox case where the id and index are the same. For my scenario they aren't.

Comment: I was trying something like this for the the dropdown item perhaps? `onClick={actor.name === selectedActorName}` similar to how you got the id. But that didn't work.

Comment: Pardon, you are totally right. For example you can use the find() function like this: `data.find((actor) => actor.id === selectedActorId).name`